# Error With total Column which calculate the summation of Row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I created a pivot query which calculate the sum of specific transaction and i want to add additional column which calculate the sum of all transaction for every ID, But my total column give me nulls only for all IDs, Any one can help with that?
this is my Query:

```
SELECT 
  AccountID
, OpeningBalance
, OpeningBalanceStatus
, ISNULL([CI], 0) AS CI
, ISNULL([CO], 0) AS CO
, ISNULL([SI], 0) AS SI
, ISNULL([CN], 0) AS CN
, ISNULL([PI], 0) AS PI
, ISNULL([JE], 0) AS JE
, ISNULL([NR], 0) AS NR
, [OpeningBalance]+[CI]+[CO]+[SI]+[CN]+[PI]+[JE]+[NR] AS TOTAL
FROM (SELECT  
    Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccountID
  , Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AmountStatus
  , Accounting.AccAccounts.AccountType
  , Accounting.AccDocumentHeader.CodeTypePart
  , AccAccounts_1.OpeningBalance
  , AccAccounts_1.OpeningBalanceStatus
  , CASE 
       WHEN AmountStatus = 'd' 
          THEN (Amount * 1) 
       WHEN AmountStatus = 'C' 
          THEN (Amount * - 1) 
       END AS NewAmount FROM Accounting.AccDocumentDetails
INNER JOIN Accounting.AccAccounts 
       ON Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccountID = Accounting.AccAccounts.ID 
 INNER JOIN Accounting.AccChartOfAccounts 
       ON Accounting.AccChartOfAccounts.ID = Accounting.AccAccounts.ParentNode 
 INNER JOIN Accounting.AccDocumentHeader 
       ON Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccDocumentHeaderID = Accounting.AccDocumentHeader.ID 
 INNER JOIN Accounting.AccAccounts AS AccAccounts_1 
       ON Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccountID = AccAccounts_1.ID) AS PivotSelect PIVOT( SUM(NewAmount) FOR CodeTypePart IN ([ci],[CO],[SI],[CN],[PI],[JE],[NR]) ) AS PVT
```

and this is my output 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V0kY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have the total column is you can use your query as sub query, then create the computation for the total on the outer query. Or you can use cte as well

```
WITH t_pvt AS (
SELECT  AccountID
       ,OpeningBalance
       ,OpeningBalanceStatus
       ,ISNULL([CI], 0) AS CI
       ,ISNULL([CO], 0) AS CO
       ,ISNULL([SI], 0) AS SI
       ,ISNULL([CN], 0) AS CN
       ,ISNULL([PI], 0) AS PI
       ,ISNULL([JE], 0) AS JE
       ,ISNULL([NR], 0) AS NR       
  FROM (SELECT  Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccountID
                ,Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AmountStatus
                ,Accounting.AccAccounts.AccountType
                ,Accounting.AccDocumentHeader.CodeTypePart
                ,AccAccounts_1.OpeningBalance
                ,AccAccounts_1.OpeningBalanceStatus
                ,CASE WHEN AmountStatus = 'd' 
                      THEN (Amount * 1) 
                      WHEN AmountStatus = 'C' 
                      THEN (Amount * - 1) 
                 END AS NewAmount 
          FROM Accounting.AccDocumentDetails
         INNER JOIN Accounting.AccAccounts 
            ON Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccountID = Accounting.AccAccounts.ID 
         INNER JOIN Accounting.AccChartOfAccounts 
            ON Accounting.AccChartOfAccounts.ID = Accounting.AccAccounts.ParentNode 
         INNER JOIN Accounting.AccDocumentHeader 
            ON Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccDocumentHeaderID = Accounting.AccDocumentHeader.ID 
         INNER JOIN Accounting.AccAccounts AS AccAccounts_1 
            ON Accounting.AccDocumentDetails.AccountID = AccAccounts_1.ID) AS PivotSelect 
 PIVOT (SUM(NewAmount) 
        FOR CodeTypePart IN ([ci],[CO],[SI],[CN],[PI],[JE],[NR])) AS PVT
)

SELECT *
       ,[OpeningBalance]+[CI]+[CO]+[SI]+[CN]+[PI]+[JE]+[NR] AS TOTAL
  FROM t_pvt
```

Comment: awesome thanks for help, it works fine but can you describe what (with) do ?and what's my error in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
With CTE
AS
( select column1 as c1 from tbl)
Select c1 from CTE
```

thats a simple example of CTE syntax and how you can use it